# java hibernate join query

Tags: java, hibernate, запрос, join

Добрый день. Есть 2 класса.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails,Serializable{
@Id
@Expose
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Expose
private String username;
@Expose
private String password;
@Expose
private String name;
@Expose
private String surname;
@Expose
private String phone;
@Expose
private String mail;
@Expose
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName=     
    "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "name",referencedColumnName =    
    "name")})
private List<UserRole>authorities = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class UserRole  implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable{
@Id
@Expose
private String name;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
private List<User>users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Пытаюсь сделать такой запрос:

```
public List<User> getManagerList() {
    Query query = null;
    mySql = "FROM User u join u.authorities a ";
    mySql+="WHERE a.name=:name";
    query = em.createQuery(mySql,User.class);
    query.setParameter("name","ROLE_MANAGER");

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Хочу получить всех пользователей с ролью Мэнэджер...Что неправильно я делаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Ми должны угадать? Или может всё таки скажите нам, что происходит вместо желаемого результата?

Comment: @Sergey, прошу прощения...Разобрался уже)

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT u FROM User u join u.authorities a WHERE a.name=:name";